# Different behaviour of segmentation fault for different number of arguments in a variadic function

Tags: c++, exception, variadic-functions

I am using a variadic function definition to handle multiple arguments of the same type (std::vector<[data_type]>). As the termination criterion, I am using the try-catch to use the exception that is thrown when the function va_arg() tries to read more variables than are passed while calling. When the number of arguments is 1-3 or 5+ (total while calling), I am getting the std::bad_alloc, which I am able to catch and successfully stop further calls to va_arg() and continue. But when I pass 4 (exactly!!) variables, I get the core dumped message and the program execution aborts. I do not understand why there is different behavior only in the case of 4 variables. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? I am using cmake version 3.16.3 on Ubuntu 20.04. I am attaching the sample function definition below:

```
template<typename T>
    void func(std::vector<T> data1d, ...) {
        /* Reading the variable number of arguments */
        va_list valist;
        // Starting the variable argument list pointer
        va_start(valist, data1d);
        // Storage container for each argument
        std::vector<T> vaitem;

        // Vector to store all the data being extracted from all the arguments
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> cols;
        // Storing the data in the first argument
        cols.push_back(data1d);
        do {
            try {
                vaitem = va_arg(valist, std::vector<T>);
            } catch (std::exception& e) {
                break;
            }
            cols.push_back(vaitem);
        } while (true);
        // Indicates the variable argument list end
        va_end(valist);
}
```

Comment: Non-trivial types are not necessary supported, it depends of implementation.

Comment: Why not use variadic template instead, which is type safe?

Comment: For the current test, I am only using float-type vectors. I have not tested any other data types. Are you suggesting that the mentioned behavior can be mitigated by using variadic templates?

Comment: `template<typename... Ts>
void func(const std::vector<Ts>&... data) { std::vector<std::vector<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>> cols{args...}; }` seems to do the job.

Comment: Or even take directly `template<typename T>void func(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>&data2d)`, and modify call to add extra `{..}` i.e. `func({v1, v2, v3, v4, v5});`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the help. I used the variadic template and it worked fine. Making a container for all the vectors actually sounds like the solution that I should've used. Thanks again.